# Is there a maximum recommeded number of users using an application with postgres database at the same time?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I am a developer and I wanted to know if there is a recommended maximum number of users an application should have, if the used DBMS is postgreSQL. Is there a maximum? Is it limited to the architecture of postgresql or is it limited only by hardware requirements of the server(s) there postgresql is installed?

I want to create an application for a customer who has 300 employees who would like to use the software at the same time. Is PostgreSQL the right DBMS for this purpose?

Comment: 300 concurrent connections shouldn't be a problem. Obviously if **all** of them start running expensive queries, this will not perform very well.

Comment: What does it mean for them to use it "at the same time"?  Presumably you won't have 300 people all hitting "submit" as fast as they can for 8 hours a day.  Presumably you won't even have 300 people logged into the database at the same time, usually they will log into an app server and the app server will use a single "app user" to log into the database.

Comment: https://youtu.be/lt9FgTeshjM?t=1743 I didn't try it. you can see that 2000 connections still can have around 200000 tps.